# https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/google-sheet-syncにてno access refresh token is setとエラーが表示される

Tags: node.js, github, firebase, google-spreadsheet

https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/google-sheet-sync

上記サイトの通り認証を得て、firebase.configで設定を行い,firebase上にdeployを行いました。実際手順は以下の通りです。

実際に行った手順

1. githubでダウンロード後、 create an OAuth Client ID でリダイレクト設定
2. node.js processファイル内にてGCP project番号の紐づけ(コマンド)
3. firebase initで初期化(コマンド)
4. firebase addでfirebaseプロジェクトと紐づけ(コマンド)
5. firebase functions:config:set googleapi.client_id="YOUR_CLIENT_ID" googleapi.client_secret="YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET" oauther認証IDを設定(コマンド)
6. firebase functions:config:set googleapi.sheet_id="YOUR_SPREADSHEET_ID"
   スプレッドシートIDを設定(コマンド)
7. firebase functions:config:set watchedpaths.data_path="THE_DATA_PATH_YOU_WANT"
   にて、realtimedb書込み先特定(コマンド)
8. 下記コードをdeploy (コマンド)
9. `https://{YOUR-PROJET-ID}.firebaseapp.com/authgoogleapi`にて認証⇒OK
10. `https://{YOUR-PROJET-ID}.{YOUR_PROJET_ID}.firebaseapp.com/testsheetwrite`にて、書込み実施⇒ realtimedbには上手く行くが、スプレッドシート書込みがエラーが出る。

```js
'use strict';

// Sample trigger function that copies new Firebase data to a Google Sheet

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();
const {OAuth2Client} = require('google-auth-library');
const {google} = require('googleapis');

// TODO: Use firebase functions:config:set to configure your googleapi object:
// googleapi.client_id = Google API client ID,
// googleapi.client_secret = client secret, and
// googleapi.sheet_id = Google Sheet id (long string in middle of sheet URL)
const CONFIG_CLIENT_ID = functions.config().googleapi.client_id;
const CONFIG_CLIENT_SECRET = functions.config().googleapi.client_secret;
const CONFIG_SHEET_ID = functions.config().googleapi.sheet_id;

// TODO: Use firebase functions:config:set to configure your watchedpaths object:
// watchedpaths.data_path = Firebase path for data to be synced to Google Sheet
const CONFIG_DATA_PATH = functions.config().watchedpaths.data_path;

// The OAuth Callback Redirect.
const FUNCTIONS_REDIRECT = `https://${process.env.GCLOUD_PROJECT}.firebaseapp.com/oauthcallback`;

// setup for authGoogleAPI
const SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets'];
const functionsOauthClient = new OAuth2Client(CONFIG_CLIENT_ID, CONFIG_CLIENT_SECRET,
  FUNCTIONS_REDIRECT);

// OAuth token cached locally.
let oauthTokens='client.secret.json';


// visit the URL for this Function to request tokens
exports.authgoogleapi = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  res.set('Cache-Control', 'private, max-age=0, s-maxage=0');
  res.redirect(functionsOauthClient.generateAuthUrl({
    access_type: 'offline',
    scope: SCOPES,
    prompt: 'consent',
  }));
});

// setup for OauthCallback
const DB_TOKEN_PATH = '/api_tokens';
const tokens=functions.config().googleapi.acess_key;
// after you grant access, you will be redirected to the URL for this Function
// this Function stores the tokens to your Firebase database
exports.oauthcallback = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  res.set('Cache-Control', 'private, max-age=0, s-maxage=0');
  const code = req.query.code;

  functionsOauthClient.getToken(code, (err, tokens) => {
    // Now tokens contains an access_token and an optional refresh_token. Save them.
    if (err) {
      return res.status(400).send(err);
    }
    return admin.database().ref(DB_TOKEN_PATH).set(tokens)
        .then(() => {
          return res.status(200).send('App successfully configured with new Credentials. '
            + 'You can now close this page.');
        });
  });
});

// trigger function to write to Sheet when new data comes in on CONFIG_DATA_PATH
exports.appendrecordtospreadsheet = functions.database.ref(`${CONFIG_DATA_PATH}/{ITEM}`).onCreate(
    (snap) => {
      const newRecord = snap.val();
      return appendPromise({
        spreadsheetId: CONFIG_SHEET_ID,
        range: 'A:C',
        valueInputOption: 'USER_ENTERED',
        insertDataOption: 'INSERT_ROWS',
        resource: {
          values: [[newRecord.firstColumn, newRecord.secondColumn, newRecord.thirdColumn]],
        },
      });
    });

// accepts an append request, returns a Promise to append it, enriching it with auth
function appendPromise(requestWithoutAuth) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    return getAuthorizedClient().then((client) => {
      const sheets = google.sheets('v4');
      const request = requestWithoutAuth;
      request.auth = client;
      return sheets.spreadsheets.values.append(request, (err, response) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(`The API returned an error: ${err}`);
          return reject(err);
        }
        return resolve(response.data);
      });
    });
  });
}

// checks if oauthTokens have been loaded into memory, and if not, retrieves them
function getAuthorizedClient() {
  if (oauthTokens) {
    return Promise.resolve(functionsOauthClient);
  }
  return admin.database().ref(DB_TOKEN_PATH).once('value').then((snapshot) => {
    oauthTokens = snapshot.val();
    functionsOauthClient.setCredentials(oauthTokens);
    return functionsOauthClient;
  });
}

// HTTPS function to write new data to CONFIG_DATA_PATH, for testing
exports.testsheetwrite = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  const random1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
  const random2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
  const random3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
  const ID = new Date().getUTCMilliseconds();
  return admin.database().ref(`${CONFIG_DATA_PATH}/${ID}`).set({
    firstColumn: random1,
    secondColumn: random2,
    thirdColumn: random3,
  }).then(() => res.status(200).send(
    `Wrote ${random1}, ${random2}, ${random3} to DB, trigger should now update Sheet.`));
});
```

エラー内容
[image: firebase errorlog]

●  // OAuth token cached locally.
    `let oauthTokens='client.secret.json';`で正しいでしょうか。
● // setup for OauthCallback
  `const DB_TOKEN_PATH = '/api_tokens';`ですが、firebaseのrealtimedb内の`/api_tokens`
  にpostmanから取得した`access_token`と`refresh_token`を格納して読み込ませる方法で
 正しいでしょうか？

長文で申し訳御座いません。もしお分かりになる方がいらっしゃいましたら教えて頂ければと
思います。宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: 元のスクリプトに対してどういう変更をしたいのかの説明があると回答がしやすいです。

Answer (score 1):

`OAuth`認証を使う場合は、ユーザーにGoogleの認証画面で認証を行ってもらうので`let oauthTokens = null;`になります。

また、サンプルのままでもリフレッシュトークンの登録はされており、1回`authgoogleapi`で認証しておくと、それ以降はずっとスプレッドシート書込みをおこなうようになっています。`OauthCallback`の方もサンプルから修正する必要はないと思います。

Comment: 早期の回答有難うございます。

やはりgithubのコードの通りlet oauthTokens=null;のままで正しいことで良かったのですね。有難うございます
firebaseに参照先追加、getToken⇒getidToken、firebaseにアクセストークンとリフレッシュトークンを登録等をしたのですがやはり上手く行かないようです。

functionsOauthClient.getToken(code, (err, tokens) => {.......});
上記部分で、画面にまずこの'App successfully configured with new Credentials. '+ 'You can now close this page.'のメッセージが出るように変えてみたいとおもい挑戦していますが,上手く行っていないのが現状です。

Comment: 試しにGitHubのサンプルを使ってみたら結構使えそうに思いました。ユーザー情報は、getTokenで取らなくても`firebase.auth().currentUser()`で取れます。